# Why are divs with margins not lining up?

Tags: html, css

When using top margin set in side a h2 in two divs floating left, i cant seem to get them to line up. Any help appreciated

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <style>
      h2{
       margin-top:10px;
      }
    </style>
    <body>
      <div>
        <div style="float:left">
          <h2>Your details</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>Security Info</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: float the other div left too.

Comment: Just so you know, the `<style>` should go inside the `<head>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <h2>Your details</h2>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left">
            <h2>Security Info</h2>
        </div>
    <br class="clear" />
</div>


  h2{
        margin-top:10px;
    }
.clear
{
    clear:both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ShTPg/